# What is reloading postfix twice at 4AM

Tags: cron, centos-7, postfix

Centos 7, postfix

I get a daily reload of Postfix. It's happening twice, back to back.

```
Jan  8 04:02:08 tn2 postfix/postfix-script[8927]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Jan  8 04:02:08 tn2 postfix/master[10112]: terminating on signal 15
Jan  8 04:02:08 tn2 postfix/postfix-script[9011]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jan  8 04:02:08 tn2 postfix/master[9013]: daemon started -- version 3.2.2, configuration /etc/postfix
Jan  8 04:02:08 tn2 postfix/postfix-script[9030]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Jan  8 04:02:08 tn2 postfix/master[9013]: terminating on signal 15
Jan  8 04:02:09 tn2 postfix/postfix-script[9112]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jan  8 04:02:09 tn2 postfix/master[9114]: daemon started -- version 3.2.2, configuration /etc/postfix
```

I've looked in the cron files, I don't see anything causing it there.  I could have missed something triggering it secondarily.

I' d be grateful for some assistance finding where this is configured and what is triggering it. Pointers on where to look, etc.

Comment: Perhaps logrotate?

Comment: Maybe, I'll have to dig through it to see if I can find a rotater doing it.  Will try. Thanks for suggestion.